# SpannableString(Builder) is not selectable in EditText

Tags: android

I have created an EditText and added some text which contains formatting to it as in the following code:

```
    EditText richTextView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rich_text);

    // this is the text we'll be operating on  
    SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");  

    // make "Lorem" (characters 0 to 5) red  
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0); 

    // make "ipsum" (characters 6 to 11) one and a half time bigger than the textbox  
    text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 6, 11, 0);  

    // make "dolor" (characters 12 to 17) display a toast message when touched  
    final Context context = this;  
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  
            Toast.makeText(context, "dolor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }  
    };  
    text.setSpan(clickableSpan, 12, 17, 0);  

    // make "sit" (characters 18 to 21) struck through  
    text.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 18, 21, 0);  

    // make "amet" (characters 22 to 26) twice as big, green and a link to this site.  
    // it's important to set the color after the URLSpan or the standard  
    // link color will override it.  
    text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 22, 26, 0);  
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 22, 26, 0);  

    // make our ClickableSpans and URLSpans work  
    richTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  

    // shove our styled text into the TextView          
    richTextView.setText(text, BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

My problem is that the text is not selectable when running the program (tried on both the emulator and my own device). If I click on any of the words except "dolor", no cursor appears, but if I type, it starts typing from before "Lorem". However, if I click "dolor", it selects the word and I can replace it (but I can't type without replacing).

I can't select any other parts of the words, and can't place the cursor where I want it (it doesn't even show up).

I am wondering how I can get normal text selection features like those that are present when using normal text instead of SpannableString or SpannableStringBuilder? (I have tried both) If I use plain text, I can select any part of any word and start inputting text from there.

**Edit1**
The text selection works in landscape mode, but not in portrait. So the code is valid to some degree...

**Edit2**
Actually text selection works in landscape mode on my phone, but not on the emulator.

Comment: Have you tried BufferType.SPANNABLE?  I think the EditText itself sets the EDITABLE...

Comment: I tried both of those. However, I just discovered that it works in landscape mode, but not in the portrait... Wierder and wierder...

Comment: Is the landscape layout different at all?

Comment: Nope, all I have is a RelativeLayout that contains the EditText.

Comment: The selection in landscape mode works on my phone, but not on the emulator actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. The problematic code was `richTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

So I just removed it. It makes the links non-responsive, but I don't really need links anyway so it's fine.

Used in this way, `setMovementMethod` was completely blocking selection by touch events for some reason (I'll have to dig into the source to figure out exactly why).

*Note to self: Don't add code till you fully understand it.*

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for the fix. Took me a few hours to find your question/answer, but it has saved me many more hours of searching. Android documentation certainly seems to encourage us to use setMovementMethod() when handling Editables/Spannables.....